# Android: Tracking App installs

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, google-play

How do I track App installs?

I have created few ads on `facebook mobile` and am getting quite a few clicks. The users are installing the app.

I wanted to know how we can track if the user really install the app after clicking the ad on `facebook mobile`.

I am able to track installs on `Google Play Console`.

Also does `facebook android API` gives me an option to track the user install (along with ad id)?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the Facebook SDK allows you to report when a user opens your app and those events are tracked as install events the first time a (Facebook) user opens your app

Documentation is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads/#advanced

Example to report an app launch / install, once you've integrated the Facebook Android SDK is:

```
com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.activateApp(context, YOUR_APP_ID);
```

In the onResume() method of your app's activities

You'll then see the installs in Facebook's Insights dashboard

Comment: @lgy Thank you, quick question, do we also know ad ID as well.?

Comment: No, but if you're running Facebook ads, the SDK sends back an attribution identifier so that Facebook knows which ad produced the install - this is reported in the ad reports (if the ad is configured to track installs of the app as one of its tracked events)

Comment: thanks how is the install count different from `google play console`? Looks like both will show same install counts.

Comment: Google play shows how many people download the binary over some time period - Facebook's insights shows how many Facebook users downloaded and opened the binary for the first time - they'd only match if **every** Google Play download was a Facebook user who opened the app and had an install event sent for them - you'll also see a discrepancy if existing users of an old version which wasn't tracking installs upgrade to a version which does as these will be 'new' installs on Facebook and possibly not on Google

Comment: @lgy, Thanks great explanation. One more please to make it clear. Lets assume a user is a `facebook` user, but goes and download it from `playstore` instead of clicking on the ad. Is this install counted by `facebook`?

Comment: Yes - Facebook reports the first time your app sends an event to the API saying that the user opened the app - regardless of where they got the app from

Comment: Does this still work if the user does not have the facebook native app installed?

Comment: @Igy Referring to your last comment : `- regardless of where they got the app from` - are you sure FB does not have mechanism to filter only those installs, triggered by ad click ? I mean, if I pay FB for ads with app installs actions, I'd like to only know how many installed from the FB ad, and not from other campaigns. I would appreciate if you can explain this, thanks.

Comment: Yes, installs attributed to facebook ads are reported separately in both Analytics and in the Ads reporting tools, but all installs are reported in Analytics, not just those which are paid